# CHashMap memory not being released on class deinitialisation

Tags: mql5

I have a class as below (simplified for the post):

```
class Person
{
public:
   Person();
   ~Person();

private:
   CHashMap<string, int> Contacts;
}
```

Now, when I deinitialise my EA, I get some logs saying:

```
X undeleted objects left
1 object of type CHashMap<string, int> left
.
.
.
X bytes of leaked memory
```

In my EA I declare as:

```
Person p;
```

And in the `OnDeinit` function I am calling:

```
void OnDeinit(const int reason)
{
  EventKillTimer();
  
  // clean objects
  delete GetPointer(p);
}
```

And in the class deinitialisation function I am doing the below:

```
Person::~Person()
{
   delete GetPointer(Contacts);
}
```

But still memory leaks... Any help as to why this is the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the memory leak was down to the fact that I was not using classes properly. The `Person` class should be declared as a pointer, and so, when calling the `delete` operator it clears the memory.

So, instead now :

`Person *p;`

And then :

```
void OnDeinit(const int reason)
{
  EventKillTimer();
  
  // clean objects
  delete p;
}
```

The issue is not with the class itself (i.e. the deinitialisation function) as that seems to clear itself fine.